# Double changing value on release version?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, double

My app works perfectly on the debug version, but when I create a release version and install it on my iphone, double values mysteriously change value. I know this by looking at the logs.

```
double amountComplete;
double possibleTotal;

for (int i = 0; i<self.tasksArray.count; i++) {
    Task *myTask = [self.tasksArray objectAtIndex:i];
    possibleTotal = possibleTotal + [myTask.size doubleValue];

    if (myTask.completed==[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]) {
        amountComplete = amountComplete + [myTask.size doubleValue];
    }

 }
```

Amount possible ends up being a hige number such as 12312213.0000.
How do I fix this and why does it only happen on the release version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ignored the "variable `amountComplete` is used uninitialized" warnings.  Change the declarations to

```
double amountComplete = 0;
double possibleTotal = 0;
```

(In debug mode, *entirely by accident*, these variables' storage locations happen to contain floating-point zeroes on entry to the loop.  Remember, undefined behavior includes the possibility of everything appearing to work just fine.)

Comment: Thank you! For some reason it wasn't giving me the warning

Comment: Dig through the Xcode settings until you find the checkbox with which to turn on warnings, then.  If you can't find a checkbox, but you do find an "additional compiler command-line options" text entry field, put `-Wall` (exactly as shown) in there.  N.B. `-Wall` is *not* all the warnings; it's all the warnings that nearly always reflect a real problem with your code.  You can get much more aggressive if you want; see here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.1/gcc/Warning-Options.html